# Как дождаться нажатия кнопки?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Когда то давно написал приложение, которое играет с пользователем в очко. При этом активно использовались конструкции типа

```
if (confirm(`Не желаете ли кон в 21?`)) {
  alert( `Атлична!` );
  playGame();
}
```

или

```
bet = prompt(`Назначьте Вашу ставку.`, '');
```

Сейчас решил отрефакторить это дело и избавиться от модальных операторов. Ну для алерта создал функцию sendMessage(message), которая помещает необходимый текст в соответствующее окошко. А вот с остальными операторами сложнее.
Сделал такой кусок разметки:

```
<form>
        <label>
          Ваш ответ:
          <input type="text" name="myForm">
        </label>
        <br>
        <div class="buttons">
          <input class="myButton sendButton" value="Отправить" type="button">
          <input class="myButton yesButton" value="Да" type="button">
          <input class="myButton noButton" value="Нет" type="button">
        </div>
      </form>
```

Сделал такой обработчик:

```
let buttonsBlock = document.body.querySelector(`.buttons`);
let input = document.body.querySelector(`input[type="text"]`);

buttonsBlock.addEventListener('click', buttonsBlockHandler);

function buttonsBlockHandler() {
  if (event.target.classList.contains(`yesButton`)) {
    return true;
      }

  if (event.target.classList.contains(`noButton`)) {
    return false;
      }

  if (event.target.classList.contains(`sendButton`)) {
    let answer = input.value;
    input.value = ``;
    return answer;
      }
}
```

Но потом понял, что если я перепишу первый фрагмент так:

```
sendMessage(`Не желаете ли кон в 21?`);
if (buttonsBlockHandler()) {}
```

то buttonsBlockHandler просто выполнится без нажатия кнопки, причем target будет не определен.
 Еще была мысль в каждом блоке кода переопределять обработчик. Типа того:

```
...
buttonsBlockHandler = function() {
if (event.target.classList.contains(`yesButton`)) {
    playGame();
...
sendMessage(`Не желаете ли кон в 21?`);
...
buttonsBlockHandler = function() {
if (event.target.classList.contains(`yesButton`)) {
    takeTheCard();
...
sendMessage(`Еще карту?`);
...
```

Но это, блин, извращение какое-то.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как дождаться нажатия кнопки?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте JQuery, там есть метод .submit
Тогда ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так

```
$(".yesButton").submit(playGame())
```

Исправил

Comment: функция запустится сразу - до клика, по понятным причинам.

Comment: попробуйте submit, и зачем сразу минусить?)
$(".yesButton").submit(playGame())

Comment: Еще раз - функция выполнится сразу... а вот если будет: $(".yesButton").submit(playGame), то существует шанс, что это будет работать как задумано. Верно?

Comment: Да, сабмит идет на отправку. Когда человек отпустил кнопку и ушел запрос.